# What is being interpolated below

Tags: perl, interpolation

Using single-quote as a delimiter protects the command from Perl's double-quote interpolation, passing it on to the shell instead:

```
$perl_info = qx(ps $$); # that's Perl's $$
$shell_info = qx'ps $$'; # that's the new shell's $$
```

What is being interpolated in the first example? Or, what is not being interpolated in the second example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$$` is the Perl special variable containing the process ID.  This is documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

For example:

```
perl -e 'print "$$\n"';
```

As you can see here, double-quote semantics are in effect, so `$$` is interpolated into the string that also contains `\n`.  When it prints, it will print your `perl` process ID.

In your first example, if your `perl` process is 4683, you will be sending the following to the shell:  `ps 4683`.

In your second example, the literal, `ps $$` is being sent to the shell.  In bash, `$$` expands to the process ID of the shell.  This is documented in [The Bash Reference Manual, Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters).  So in the first example you're invoking `ps` with the process ID of the `perl` process.  In the second example you're invoking `ps` with the process ID of the shell.

Comment: (long comment deleted)... We don't close homework questions for being homework.  And questions that remain open should receive answers.  I tried to provide links where the OP might study on his own in the future.  It's not my responsibility to ensure that he does his own work, and gains the education he paid for.  I tried to help him in that direction.  The rest is his job.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't criticizing you for answering, just wondering if you'd noticed

Comment: :) No problem. I hadn't noticed though.  I just assumed it was yet another question that could have been answered by knowing where to look.